# SKLearn ElasticNetCV: Looking for a similar cross-validation-error-plot to Matlab's lassoPlot or R's plot(cv.glmnet(x,y))

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV and I would like to get a similar figure as Matlab provides with `lassoPlot` with `plottype=CV` or R's `plot(cv.glmnet(x,y))`, i.e., a plot of the cross validations errors over various alphas (note, in Matlab and R this parameter is called lambda). Here is an example:

```
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats as stats

# toy example
# generate 200 samples of five-dimensional artificial data X from a 
# exponential distributions with various means:
X = np.zeros( (200,5 ) )
for col in range(5):
    X[ :, col ] = stats.expon.rvs( scale=1.0/(col+1) )

# generate response data Y = X*r + eps where r has just two nonzero
# components, and the noise eps is normal with standard deviation 0.1:
r = np.array( [ 0, 2, 0, -3, 0 ] )
Y = np.dot(X,r) + sp.randn( 200 )*0.1

enet = lm.ElasticNetCV()

alphas,coefs, _ = enet.path( X, Y )

# plot regulization paths    
plt.plot( -np.log10(alphas), coefs.T, linestyle='-' )
plt.show()
```

I would like to plot also in a separate figure the cross validation error for each alpha. But It seems that ElasticNetCV.path() does not return a mse vector. Is there a simliar functionality in sklearn to `Matlab.lassoPlot` with `plottype='CV'` see: http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/lasso-and-elastic-net.html or R's `cv.glmnet(x,y)` https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html. Alternatively, I would implement it using `sklearn.cross_validation`. Do you have any suggestions?